# FPGA Parallel output timing to satisfy input timing

Tags: delay, fpga, timing, propagation, soc

Let's say a FPGA reads flip-flop D and outputs Q on the second rising edge of a CLK (figeure1). How can this satisfy the input setup time [TpdSU] of another device (figure2)?
Do they generally not use the same CLK for the flip-flops and the output CLK towards another device?
Or does a input device read the data on the 3th rising edge of the CLK?

Maybe I'm completely off and it is something different.

[image: FPGA flip-flow]

[image: Parallel Input Timing]

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [electronics.SE] than [SO]

Comment: When you say "*a FPGA reads flip-flop D*", **when** exactly does it read that? It sounds as if it would read that signal on the first rising edge of CLK, but that doesn't match your figure

Comment: On the first CLK rising edge D = 0 so Q = 0, then on the 2nd D = 1 so Q = 1, but Q only goes high at the rising edge of the CLK, so if Q and CLK are connected to another device, how can it satisfy the setup time. Q only goes high at the rising edge

Comment: I assume that the internal CLK to the flip-flops are at least twice as fast as the outputted PCLK, so that it can send data before sending a new rising edge on the output PCLK